# How to search for product by SKU on frontend of website

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Searching product by SKU on frontend display no product found. I created a plugin and try and error, but it always show 0 product found.

```
 add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wooSearchFrontEnd' );
 function wooSearchFrontEnd( $query_vars ) {
 global $typenow;
 global $wpdb;
 global $pagenow;

 $search_term = $query_vars->query_vars['s'];
 $search_postype = $query_vars->query_vars['post_type'];

  if ( $search_term != '' && $search_postype == 'product' ) {
      $meta_query = array( 'relation' => 'OR',
      array(
        'key' => '_sku',
        'value' => get_query_var( 's' ),
        'compare' => 'LIKE'
       )
    );
    $query_vars->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );

  }
  return $query_vars;

}
```

Answer (score -2):

If you want to write this yourself,  you will need a little more code and at least a wpdb query.

But if you are fine with using a plugin, please try this Ajax Search for WooCommerce. It allows searching for SKU as well:
https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/ajax-search-for-woocommerce/

Have a nice day
Saskia

Comment: I don't want to use Ajax.